# How to filter out green color using CSS or javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want only red and blue color component in the image (or text).
Can I use CSS 'filter' feature for that ? If yes, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: show your code pls. did you do anything for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in CSS AFAIK, but you can use Canvas API to obtain image data via getImageData and filter out the required component manually with javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `filter()` property of CSS ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)). It can apply effects on HTML elements including modifying colors. For your specific case, it would be required to define an own filter.

Look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-browser-wgvu8?file=/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .filter-this {
          filter: url(#myfilter);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body class="filter-this">

    <p style="color: red">
        I am red
    </p>
    <p style="color: green">
        I am green
    </p>
    <p style="color: blue">
        I am blue
    </p>
    <p style="color: yellow">
        I am yellow
    </p>
    <svg>
    <filter id="myfilter">
     <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
         values="
             1 0 0 0 0
             0 0 0 0 0
             0 0 1 0 0
             0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
    </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

The value of the `feColorMatrix` is a matrix which will be multiplied with every pixel. The input vectors are RGBa values appended with a `1` (`1 1 0 1 1` for yellow). By making the second row of the transformation matrix all zero, it removes the green component turning the green text to black and the yellow text to red.